# Whole DIV clickable except while hovering a span

Tags: jquery

I am using a script by CSS-Tricks, which is pretty straightforward except my scenario includes a little tricky area :)

The script:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
   return false;
});
```

This works perfectly except inside my DIV I have a span containing an icon that needs to trigger a tooltip but not link anywhere (already working fine).

My question:
Is it possible for the above script to make the whole DIV clickable EXCEPT while hovering a child span?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your tooltip code you can stop the click from [bubbling up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$(".myBox span").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  //show tooltip
});
```

This stops the `click` event from going to the parent `.myBox` `<div>` from that tooltip `<span>`, meaning that your current [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler won't fire/redirect the page.

Comment: Hi Nick thank you for the quick reply. Isn't this approach the other way around? Meaning the URL is on the span rather than the DIV?

Comment: @ale - you'd use this in addition to your current code...when clicking in the span, nothing happens but the tooltip, when clicking anywhere else...the `click` bubbles up and the handler in your question works, make sense?

Comment: Sorry one last question. Can I change the cursor to clearly show the whole area is a link?

Comment: @ale - yup, just add a `cursor: pointer` CSS style to that `<div>`, for example: `.myBox { cursor: pointer; }`, possibly a `.myBox span { cursor: default; }` as well for the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You could the event target:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(e){
    if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'SPAN') {
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
        return false;
    }
 });
```

However, as Nick points out in the comments, this assumes that there will be no non-span children of the span.  Since you are inserting a tooltip, Nick's solution is (inevitably) the better way to go.

Comment: True. Edited to acknowledge the particular relevance of this point to a tooltip situation...

Comment: What if the child span is turned into an child DIV with a specific class. Say the outer DIV has class .myBox, and the inner div containing the tooltip icon has class .myInfoBox?

Comment: Then you'd need to do `if (0 === $(e.target).closest('.myInfoBox').length) {`

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question would be, does the span need to be a child of the div?  I would put the span before or after the div tag, set its position to relative or absolute, then push it into the div tag.  Like so:

```
<span style="position:relative;top:-20px;left:-20px">Icon</span>
<div> Do your div stuff here </div>
```

This should work.  You might need to include a z-index of 1 or 2 for the span, but I doubt this.  What this will do is put the div in behind, and the span in front; now the span won't react to your click handler.  Hope this works!

Comment: Hi bozdoz that's a different way of looking at it. I will give it a try and see if it works. Cheers!